# How to set a field value in mongoose model to be addition of two fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two fields wallet and bank both stores a Integer.
I want to insure that another field named total should have value of computed value of wallet and bank..

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    wallet: { type: Number, default: 500 },
    bank: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    total: { type: Number},
})

module.exports = { User: mongoose.model("User", User) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [mongoose virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals).

In your case it would look something like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    wallet: { type: Number, default: 500 },
    bank: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    total: { type: Number},
}, {
  virtuals: {
    total: {
      get() {
        return this.wallet + this.bank;
      }
    }
  }
})

module.exports = { User: mongoose.model("User", User) }
```

mongoose will call the getter function every time you access the `total` property